# Identifying and removing extra tabs in a tab delimited text file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a text files with 120 columns and thousands of rows where the delimiter is a tab. In some rows, there is an extra tab present making it seem, in that row, like there are 121 columns. The location of this extra tab is not known to be the same for all the text files.

I am wondering if anyone has any thoughts on efficiently locating the extra tab and removing it programmatically.

Comment: Are there any rows where a column value is absent, thus there are legitimately two consecutive tabs?  If so, then I don't see any way to easily do this.  If not, then it's simple, just replace all occurrences of two consecutive tabs with a single tab.

Comment: @JohnGordon In some cases the column value is an NaN. So, I need to find a way to identify where the extra tabs are and remove them otherwise I get errors when trying to read the file in with pandas. 

I have thought about running through each line and counting the number of tabs between non empty strings and then, where an extra tab exists, removing it. But I am not sure if this is the most efficient way to deal with this issue.

Comment: I asked if there were any rows where a column value is _absent_, meaning there would legitimately be two consecutive tabs.  I don't think NaN falls into that case.

Comment: @JohnGordon yes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex as separator in [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

Use `'\t+'` (one or more tabulations):

```
df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv', sep='\t+', engine='python')
```